# Replace one column values by another column values in a table using SQL

Tags: sql

I need help to write a SQL query that will replace values in one column by another column values in the same table. For example, given the following table, I want to replace values in column 2 by values in column 1. I think the "UPDATE table SET ..." clause would help but don't know how to use it. Can any one help me, please ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5c3L.png)

Comment: `UPDATE table SET column2 = colum1 WHERE 1=1`  see home page https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, something else)? Please add the tag of your database to your question. See [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) to know why tagging is important. Also, as per the [*How to ask* guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/#251362).

Comment: Hello, 

Thank you very much for the answer. Indeed I am using a Postgres database. Ok, I noted for the tag. For next time I will be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table t1 
SET column1 = (SELECT column2 FROM table t2 WHERE t1.column1 = t2.column1);
```

Comment: that is unnecessary, see my comment, which works perfectly